# Loop of function with plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have got a function which returns me some variables and also plotting a graph (histogram). I would like to run that function in loop and plot on seperate graph each result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def func_graph(a, b):
   plt.hist(a, density=True, bins=10)
   return sum(a), b


a = [np.random.randn(1000), np.random.randn(1000), np.random.randn(1000)]
b = 5
List_of_results = [func_graph(x,b) for x in a]
```

so the after printing `List_of_results[0]` I would get `(sum(a), b)` of first `a` item and its plot (right now its plotting all graphs)

How can I achieve it?

I'm doing it in Jupyter

Answer (score 0):

You need to store and return the histogram.

```
def func_graph(a, b):
   histogram = plt.hist(a, density=True, bins=10)
   return sum(a), b, histogram
```

Comment: that suggestion creates me extra variable in my results (which is array with values of histogram to print it later) but still prints all histograms on 1 graph. I tried to use `plt.figure()` before `plt.hist(...)` but anyway it prints me all graphs (not only from `List_of_results[0]`), but they are separate at least